# Subtitles below a part

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using LateX for my thesis.
Is there a way to insert strictly below a part a subtitle that does not appear in the toc?

Answer (score 5):

Use the optional argument of `\part`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part[the title for the toc]
     {The title for the document\\[\bigskipamount] 
      \large with a small subtitle}

foo
\end{document}
```